# SQL Server Management Studio 2014 stops working after installing SSDT-BI for visual studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

Initially I had installed SQL Server 2014. Then I installed SSDT-BI for visual studio 2013 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42313)

I have installed SSDT-BI using a new SQL instance when prompted. Also in my machine it is not installed MS Visual Studio 2013.

After installation completes, I try to execute SQL Server Management Studio 2014 but below error message appears:

```
Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application.
```

So now I cannot start SQL Server Management Studio 2014...

I uninstalled visual studio 2010 shell because I thought it was not necessary (I do not have installed neither visual studio 2010 nor any versions of visual studio).

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Try installing SSMS 2016 stand alone. It comes with some cool features. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: @vercelli I forgot to say that I uninstalled visual studio 2010 shell because I thought it was not necessary (I do not have installed neither visual studio 2010 nor any versions of visual studio). I don't know if it is necessary for SSMS 2014 to execute.

Comment: VS is not necessary for SSMS to run, but it's a requirement for SSDT-BI.
Are you going to develop a SSAS,SSRS or SSIS project?

Comment: @vercelli only to develop reports, so I guess with SSDT-BI installed is necessary, right? In fact I can open ssdt projects and deploy them.

Comment: Yes, it is. I would install VS 2015 and SSDT for VS 2015

Comment: And also I would install SSMS 2016 standalone

Comment: @vercelli Well my customer have sql server 2014, so I cannot install SSMS16. Could I try to repair SQL Server 2014 through installation center? but I have a doubt: If I try to repair could I lose my current configuration for SQL Server Reporting services?

Comment: We also have SqlServer 2014 and work with SSMS 2016 since it's a standalone installation with frequent updates (don't need to install SqlServer).

Comment: @vercelli ok, one more question. If I try to repair SQL Server 2014, Will my current configuration for SQL Server Reporting Services be lost? or it will be kept after repairing SQL Server? Maybe it is safer to install SSMS as a standalone...One thing more, my created databases, despite SSMS is not working now, they are not affected, right? they still are there, right? they have not been removed I mean so If I install SSMS standalone again, once logged in into SQL Server I will see again my databases, right?

Comment: I'm really not sure if you will lose something on reinstallation. Can't help you with that.

Comment: I have solved it by reinstalling MS Visual Studio 2010 shell (isolated).